# SAS date format when loaded in is strange

Tags: date, sas, format

This is the original format of my date column when i import it. How do I change to it something like `30April2019`

[[image: pic]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your import options used datetime format, instead of date format.

Try declaring import format as `DATE9.` format

Answer (score 0):

Your `DATE` column is a datetime value, which is different than a date value.

Use the format `DTDATE9.` so that the datetime value is rendered (represented) as *dd-mon-yyyy* when viewing.  There are many other `DT*` formats available for rendering the value in other representations.

Example:

```
data have;
  mydate = datetime(); * current date time;

  mydate_raw_unformatted = mydate;

  format mydate dtdate9.;
run;

proc print data=have;
run;
```

[image]